# Decrypt/convert stock quotes

Tags: json, excel, encryption, stockquotes, vba

I am trying to get stock quotes from the webpage “plus500.com”. The values are provided in json and I am able to get the data into excel. But I do not know how to encrypt or convert the provided information. I tried to decrypt the values with base64 but it was not working.

Here's an example of the close rate for gold: The values should be between 1292 and 1304. How to convert or decrypt this data?

Close Rate:

```
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…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
```

Comment: I guess the point of this encryption is for u to not be able to decrypt it. As this kind of information is valuable, depending on the accuracy (time-wise) of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your your reply. But my web browser can display this information into dynamic charts. So the browser actually knows the right key. Or am I drawing the wrong conclusions?

Comment: Doesn't look like anything to me. If it's encrypted then you aren't going to decrypt it without a key. If it's converted to some other base then you have a puzzle on your hands. That doesn't appear to be base64 of ascii, utf8, or any other regular-joe character encoding.

Comment: But isn’t there a chance that my web browser knows the key? For example the SHA256 can be displayed. Also the web browser displays the decrypted data into a chart. So for me it is not possible to get the whole chart information into a table.

Comment: open website in chrome, open dev console, go to sources, click pause on top right corner of the dev window. now reproduce whatever action you are doing inside your browser to update the rate and step line by line in the dev console until you find out how your browser retrieves and interprets this data

Comment: I made request to URL [https://www.plus500.com/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=11](https://www.plus500.com/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=11) and seems the response contains no encrypted data, all values are available for parsing.

Comment: @omegastripes , thank you for the URL. But I am trying to get the data from: https://trade.plus500.com/ClientRequest/GetChartDataImm?InstrumentID=11&FeedResolutionLevel=1&Type=Sell&MaxNumberOfCandles=&SessionID=65775029-dcb0-43d0-ab11-09c186f4a4eb&SubSessionID=24557f54-6f34-4ccd-b039-3c6feef90df3
Because I would like to get the whole historical data.